# Extracting title of table from Word (.docx) using Python

Tags: python, win32com, python-docx

I have a Word (.docx) document which has title/headings and their corresponding tables below the titles as shown below:

```
1.1.1.1 Table_Title_001

Name        Gautham

College     Oxford

University  Cambridge

1.1.1.2 Table_Title_002

Name        Krishnan

College     Harvard

University  Stanford
```

Is there any way to extract the title of each table using Python? The documentation for win32com or python-docx is not very clear regarding this.

Comment: Is Word installed on the machine where the program runs? Or are you looking for a solution which could run, for example, on a Linux server?

Comment: @Doc Brown Word is installed on my machine. I'm expecting some help in  extracting the table's title using any external Python modules like the win32com.client API's or Python-docx. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then your general strategy should be: google for how to do what you want in VBA. Port the solution to Python using win32com (see http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html). Note Word's COM API and the VBA API are almost identical.

Comment: Thank you @Doc Brown, I did exactly the same and it sort of works now. Experimenting with different win32com API, and as you said they are very identical to VBA API's.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not on Windows right now, so I can't test it out locally, but Word tables have a [Title property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff835972.aspx) that seems to be what you're looking for.

Using `win32com`, it'd look something like:

```
from win32com import client
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
document = word.Documents.Open(path_to_docx)

titles = [table.Title for table in document.Tables]
```

Comment: This answer is not very helpful as long as it does not tell which technology or module is used to access the word doc. Is this using COM automation (which requires Word to be installed)? Or python-docx? Or something completely different?

Comment: I though the OP was using `win32com` but you're right, I'll edit my answer to add some clarity.

Comment: Table.Title property of Word was not useful (I couldn't understand it even after reading the , but I used ListParagraphs with win32com client to accomplish the same! Nevertheless, appreciate your help @magni-

Comment: Ahh, these were paragraph titles rather than table titles?

Comment: Yes, when these headings are numbered like 1.1.1, 1.1.2, they are actually ListParagraphs !

Comment: And the ListParagraphs do not count the same numbered headings if they appear in the Table of Contents also, which is exactly what i wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Using python-docx, these are very easily readable. In python-docx these are not actually titles, they are paragraphs. Starting off I would recommend looking at [this site](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/) so you get an understanding of how it works.

```python
from docx import Document
doc = Document("wordfile.docx")
for para in doc.paragraphs:
     print(para.text)
```

This will print out every paragraph in the current document. If you only have titles and tables in your file this will work fine for you